# Express, make all routes begin with /api

Tags: javascript, express

Is there any way to make all the routes that express accepts start with /api without having to define it explicitly?

Current:

```
this.app.get('/api/endpoint-A', (req, res) => {
   return res.send('A');
});
this.app.get('/api/endpoint-B', (req, res) => {
   return res.send('B');
});
```

Objective:

```
this.app.get('/endpoint-A', (req, res) => {//https:host.com/api/endpoint-A
   return res.send('A');
});
this.app.get('/endpoint-B', (req, res) => {//https:host.com/api/endpoint-B
   return res.send('B');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
app.use('/api/:version/', router);
```

after you have created a base express router.